# How to distribute a dataframe's rows among list elements

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list that comprises a number of dataframes for different securities: for each security there's a date and a reading. I also have a dataframe that has an additional reading-date pair for each security as a row. I'd like to append the additional reading to the appropriate dataframe element in the list.

I can manage this interactively by using

```
list_name %>% map_df(slice, .id = "id")
```

to convert the list to a dataframe, append the new readings with bind_rows and then split to convert back to a list.

BUT: I'm trying to convert this into a function for use in a package. One of the columns in the data is a date. As a standalone function, it also works. But when packaged and loaded as a library, it throws an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("slice_") : 
  no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an object of class "Date"
```

For example, if I have a list z and dataframe d

```
b <- data.frame(Rank = c(1, 2, 3), Value = c("A", "B", "C"))
c <- data.frame(Rank = c(1, 2, 3), Value = c("A", "B", "C"))
z <- list(Z = b, Y =c)
d <- data.frame(Sec = c("B", "C"), Rank = 4, Value = c("D"))
```

I'd like the result to be

```
$Z
  Rank Value
1    1     A
2    2     B
3    3     C
4    4     D

$Y
  Rank Value
1    1     A
2    2     B
3    3     C
4    4     D
```

But have no idea where to start. I've tried the usual googling approaches, but can't get the right words to bring up an answer.

Comment: Do you need a join `map(z, ~ full_join(.x, d[-1]) %>% distinct)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to `split` the 'd' dataset by the 'Sec' with `group_split` and use that in `map2` to bind the rows with the corresponding elements of 'z'

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
   group_split(Sec, keep = FALSE) %>%
   map2(z, ., bind_rows)
#$Z
#  Rank Value
#1    1     A
#2    2     B
#3    3     C
#4    4     D

#$Y
#  Rank Value
#1    1     A
#2    2     B
#3    3     C
#4    4     D
```

Comment: This is the easiest to answer understand, but doesn't give the correct results. Group_split doesn't preserve the original order, producing an alphabetically sorted list. So this will work correctly only if the original list is also alphabetical. A bit more searching turns up this:  `z1 <- z[order(names(z))]` to sort the original list by name alphabetically. And then bind_rows works correctly.

Comment: @Slurp  To split in the same order, do `d %>% group_split(Sec = factor(Sec, levels = unique(Sec)), keep = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
Map(rbind, A= z, B = lapply(split(d,d$Sec), function(x){x[-1]}))

# $Z
#      Rank Value
# A.1    1     A
# A.2    2     B
# A.3    3     C
# B      4     D
# 
# $Y
#      Rank Value
# A.1    1     A
# A.2    2     B
# A.3    3     C
# B      4     D
```